# What jQuery method do I put here if I want it to be triggered right when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, live, jquery

What do I replace the question marks with if I want the class to be added when the page is loaded?

```
$("form#signupform input#email").live("????", function() {
    $(this).addClass("launchrock");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd replace more than that.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("form#signupform input#email").addClass("launchrock");
});
```

Assuming by page you mean page with all assets; if not, use `$(function() { ... })` which only waits for the DOM API to be ready for use.

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load(function(){...});` is called when the images have loaded, `$(document).ready(function(){...});` will be called as soo as the js/css/dom has been loaded and can execute

read this for more information tho

http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/